# What are some overlaps between Computational Scientist and Mechanical Engineering?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am a fairly recent graduate (I graduated December of 2015 with a Bachelor's of Science in Computational Science) and since graduating I have had an increasing desire to get involved in engineering.

What areas of engineering employ aspects of computational science?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like an [academic guidance question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/261/1832). Such questions often involve personal choice and can probably be better answered by an adviser or counselor. We do not believe this site's format is well-suited to such questions, which are therefore considered off-topic.

Comment: @Wasabi I am not asking for academic guidance, I'm asking for career guidance. If you would still rather me not ask it here could you redirect me to a different forum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several places Computational Science and Mechanical Engineering overlap. Computation is a tool that many engineers use on a daily basis to make design decisions.

1. [Computational Fluid Dynamics (CFD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_fluid_dynamics)- Learn [OpenFOAM](http://www.openfoam.com/) and do some contracting.
2. [Finite Element Analysis (FEA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method)- Learn OpenFoam or [GMSH](http://gmsh.info/) and do some contracting.
3. Computation is the only way to solve many ugly differential equations, and a much easier route to solving many of the solvable ones. Engineers know math, but we don't necessarily like math and are not awesome at it. Large engineering firms benefit from in-house math, computational, and data handling expertise.
4. Find a research firm or supercomputing contractor that hires lots of engineers and computational scientists.
5. Any other [computational science related field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_science#Related_fields)

Comment: 3. nultibody simulation is a prime example of this. Not only does it have computation challenges that are unsolved but its tedious to do by hand and does benefit from realtime optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I learned the finite element method in school and will look into GMSH.

Comment: @joojaa @ eric Is there a specific job title commonly associated with this type of work?

Comment: @computhomas yes analyst

Comment: @joojaa I'm sorry to ask so many questions, but if I were to search for these jobs on a job board would engineering analyst come up with this type of thing? Analyst will surely be too broad

Comment: @computhomas no it would be either FEM analyst, multibody analyst etc but namings vary wildly across the globe.